# @ExceptionHandler returns a lot of logs from RuntimeException while handling user defined exception

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception

I am learning the Spring boot framework. I am trying to implement exception handling at controller level by using @ExceptionHandler. I am able to handle the thrown user defined exception that extends the RuntimeException but the  response has a lot more that what i intended to see. It contains cause, stack-trace from the Run-time Exception class but i do not want those in the response.

Following is the code  for @ExceptionHandler

```
@ExceptionHandler(InvalidPassengerNameException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<InvalidPassengerNameException> handleInvalidPassengerNameException(InvalidPassengerNameException exc) {
        InvalidPassengerNameException iPNE =  new InvalidPassengerNameException();
        iPNE.setErrorCode("E400");
        iPNE.setErrorMessage("PAssenger name should be more than 8 characters");
        return new ResponseEntity<InvalidPassengerNameException>(iPNE, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
    }
```

Following is my User Defined Exception class:

```
public class InvalidPassengerNameException extends RuntimeException{
private String errorCode;
private String errorMessage;
public String getErrorCode() {
    return errorCode;
}
public void setErrorCode(String errorCode) {
    this.errorCode = errorCode;
}
public String getErrorMessage() {
    return errorMessage;
}
public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
}
}
```

When the exception is handled by the defined handler, the log contains a lot more that what i inteded to see:

```
{
    "cause": null,
    "stackTrace": [
        {
            "methodName": "handleInvalidPassengerNameException",
            "fileName": "PassengerController.java",
            "lineNumber": 32,
            "className": "com.booking.application.controller.PassengerController",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "invoke0",
            "fileName": "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java",
            "lineNumber": -2,
            "className": "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl",
            "nativeMethod": true
        },
        {
            "methodName": "invoke",
            "fileName": "NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java",
            "lineNumber": 62,
            "className": "sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "invoke",
            "fileName": "DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java",
            "lineNumber": 43,
            "className": "sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "invoke",
            "fileName": "Method.java",
            "lineNumber": 498,
            "className": "java.lang.reflect.Method",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doInvoke",
            "fileName": "InvocableHandlerMethod.java",
            "lineNumber": 190,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "invokeForRequest",
            "fileName": "InvocableHandlerMethod.java",
            "lineNumber": 138,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "invokeAndHandle",
            "fileName": "ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java",
            "lineNumber": 106,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doResolveHandlerMethodException",
            "fileName": "ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java",
            "lineNumber": 407,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doResolveException",
            "fileName": "AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java",
            "lineNumber": 61,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "resolveException",
            "fileName": "AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java",
            "lineNumber": 141,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "resolveException",
            "fileName": "HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java",
            "lineNumber": 80,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "processHandlerException",
            "fileName": "DispatcherServlet.java",
            "lineNumber": 1300,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "processDispatchResult",
            "fileName": "DispatcherServlet.java",
            "lineNumber": 1111,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doDispatch",
            "fileName": "DispatcherServlet.java",
            "lineNumber": 1057,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doService",
            "fileName": "DispatcherServlet.java",
            "lineNumber": 943,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "processRequest",
            "fileName": "FrameworkServlet.java",
            "lineNumber": 1006,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doPost",
            "fileName": "FrameworkServlet.java",
            "lineNumber": 909,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "service",
            "fileName": "HttpServlet.java",
            "lineNumber": 660,
            "className": "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "service",
            "fileName": "FrameworkServlet.java",
            "lineNumber": 883,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "service",
            "fileName": "HttpServlet.java",
            "lineNumber": 741,
            "className": "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
            "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
            "lineNumber": 231,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
            "lineNumber": 166,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "WsFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 53,
            "className": "org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
            "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
            "lineNumber": 193,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
            "lineNumber": 166,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
            "fileName": "RequestContextFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 100,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 119,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
            "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
            "lineNumber": 193,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
            "lineNumber": 166,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
            "fileName": "FormContentFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 93,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 119,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
            "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
            "lineNumber": 193,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
            "lineNumber": 166,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doFilterInternal",
            "fileName": "CharacterEncodingFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 201,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "OncePerRequestFilter.java",
            "lineNumber": 119,
            "className": "org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "internalDoFilter",
            "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
            "lineNumber": 193,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doFilter",
            "fileName": "ApplicationFilterChain.java",
            "lineNumber": 166,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "invoke",
            "fileName": "StandardWrapperValve.java",
            "lineNumber": 202,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "invoke",
            "fileName": "StandardContextValve.java",
            "lineNumber": 96,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "invoke",
            "fileName": "AuthenticatorBase.java",
            "lineNumber": 526,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "invoke",
            "fileName": "StandardHostValve.java",
            "lineNumber": 139,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "invoke",
            "fileName": "ErrorReportValve.java",
            "lineNumber": 92,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "invoke",
            "fileName": "StandardEngineValve.java",
            "lineNumber": 74,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "service",
            "fileName": "CoyoteAdapter.java",
            "lineNumber": 343,
            "className": "org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "service",
            "fileName": "Http11Processor.java",
            "lineNumber": 367,
            "className": "org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "process",
            "fileName": "AbstractProcessorLight.java",
            "lineNumber": 65,
            "className": "org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "process",
            "fileName": "AbstractProtocol.java",
            "lineNumber": 860,
            "className": "org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "doRun",
            "fileName": "NioEndpoint.java",
            "lineNumber": 1591,
            "className": "org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "run",
            "fileName": "SocketProcessorBase.java",
            "lineNumber": 49,
            "className": "org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "runWorker",
            "fileName": "ThreadPoolExecutor.java",
            "lineNumber": 1149,
            "className": "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "run",
            "fileName": "ThreadPoolExecutor.java",
            "lineNumber": 624,
            "className": "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "run",
            "fileName": "TaskThread.java",
            "lineNumber": 61,
            "className": "org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable",
            "nativeMethod": false
        },
        {
            "methodName": "run",
            "fileName": "Thread.java",
            "lineNumber": 748,
            "className": "java.lang.Thread",
            "nativeMethod": false
        }
    ],
    "errorCode": "E400",
    "errorMessage": "Passenger name should be more than 8 characters",
    "localizedMessage": null,
    "message": null,
    "suppressed": []
}
```

What I intended to see is:

```
"errorCode": "E400",
"errorMessage": "Passenger name should be more than 8 characters",
```

What am I missing? I know a global @ControllerAdvice would help. But I want to learn why this happens and how can this be  implemented to  achieve the intended response as output ?

Comment: Where did you put the method with @ExceptionHandler annotation?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes  , I think exceptionHandler is not getting loaded at all

Comment: @SimonMartinelli - It is within the Controller class. I think it is getting loaded because I can see the Exception being handled Am i not right. I do not have  Controller Adivce. I do not want to handle it at global level. I want at Controller level only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@ExceptionHandler` is working fine. However, you are extending `RuntimeException`, which comes with a `getCause()`, `getStackTrace()`, ... . Jackson serializes all these fields to JSON, which is why you see a `stacktrace` and a `cause` field.

To solve this, you can either create a dedicated DTO for your errors which does not extend from `RuntimeException`, for example:

```java
public class ErrorMessageDTO {
    private final String errorCode;
    private final String errorMessage;

    // Constructors + Getters + Setters
}
```

And now you can use this within your `@ExceptionHandler`:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(InvalidPassengerNameException.class)
public ResponseEntity<ErrorMessageDTO> handleInvalidPassengerNameException(InvalidPassengerNameException exc) {
    ErrorMessageDTO message = new ErrorMessageDTO("E400", "Passenger name should be more than 8 characters");
    return new ResponseEntity<ErrorMessageDTO>(message, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
}
```

Alternatively, you can override the getters of `RuntimeException` and annotate them with `@JsonIgnore`:

```java
public class InvalidPassengerNameException extends RuntimeException {
    // Fields + Getters + Setters

    @JsonIgnore
    @Override
    public Throwable getCause() {
        return super.getCause();
    }
}
```

In this case, the first solution would be the best. You are already returning a new object within your `@ExceptionHandler`, and there's no more reason for this new object to extend from `RuntimeException`.

Comment: When we do not extend RuntimeException, the ExceptionHandler will complain as Type mismatch: cannot convert from Class<InvalidPassengerNameException> to Class<? extends Throwable>[]... How does that work ?

Comment: You still have to use the `@ExceptionHandler(InvalidPassengerNameException.class)`. You should only use the `ErrorMessageDTO` as the return type.

Comment: @mack I'ved edited my answer to clarify what the entire exception handler should look like, does that help?